# Is there a way to build create-react-app project besides errors and warnings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, tizen-web-app

I am trying to use React to build an application for Samsung TV (Tizen) and I need to access native Tizen API but when I add a script tag and try to call that script in my code, I get `'webapis' is not defined` error. If I would succesfully build that project, I wouldn't get that error because TV holds `webapis` script, so is there a way to skip errors while building create-react-app application?

Comment: Are you building a mobile app or a web app? ```create-react-app``` generates an app with ReactJS, but a Native API or SDK could only be used on a mobile platform, using React Native.

Comment: @Chris B. I want to build TV app using React.